# Keep Linies between two expressions (exclusive) from a file using python

Tags: python, regex, flags

Sample File:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
start of a pattern
apple
orange
red
green
blue
end of a pattern
eee
fff
www
```

I need to keep the lines between the two tags : `TAG1 and TAG2`

I am able to delete the lines before `TAG1`. Stuck on how to delete lines after `TAG2`?

```
TAG1 = 'start of a pattern'
TAG2 = 'end of a pattern'

tag_found = False
with open('input.txt') as in_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if not tag_found:
                if line.strip() == TAG1:
                    tag_found = True
            else:
                out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: You have a `tag_found` variable. You need to have both `tag1_found` and `tag2_found`, and only print when one is true and not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a condition in the else block:

```
else:
    if line.strip() == TAG2:
        break    # Break out of the loop
    out_file.write(line)
```

But you could do it without any intermediate variables:

```
while next(in_file).strip() != TAG1:  # Consume all lines up to TAG1
    pass

for line in in_file:
    if line.strip() == TAG2:          # Break at TAG2
        break
    out_file.write(line)
```